# How does association between Directory and Property/Variable work in WiX?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

In Wix (3.11) there seems to be an implicit link between a  with the Id 'ProgramFilesFolder' and the 'ProgramFilesFolder' variable.  That is, a directory with that id will be named according to the property value.

When I try replicating this on my own with a "Test" directory:

```
<Property Id="Test" Value="Test"/>

<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
     <Directory Id="Test"/>
       ...
```

I get a warning from WiX, and the installer actually hangs.  I've also tried declaring "Test" as a WixVariable, but in that case it appeared the  element was simply ignored - iow, no "Test" folder was created.

My question is how does this implicit link work for WiX variables, but not for my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProgramFilesFolder isn't really a WiX variable or Id. It's a Windows Installer standard property that you can't change - it refers to the 32-bit Program Files path on the system that you're installing on. Your Test directory will be beneath the Program Files folder.

There isn't enough of your WiX source to see what's going on, but just declaring those locations and properties won't create the directories if nothing is installed there. A complete working example of the issue would be useful.

Comment: @Dan Just to interpose, here is a list of such properties: [System Folder Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905(v=vs.85).aspx#system_folder_properties).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define a separate property for your directory, the id of the directory doubles as a property because [directories are properties](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robmen/2006/10/17/deciphering-the-msi-directory-table-part-7-directories-are-properties/). If the property (directory id) is all uppercase, it becomes a [public property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905(v=vs.85).aspx), and can be set from the command line.

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
     <Directory Id="TEST" Name="Test" />
       ...
```

Setting the install path of the TEST directory from the [command line](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367988(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
msiexec /i A:\Example.msi TEST=c:\Example\Test /qn
```

The directory id "ProgramFilesFolder" is a bit different because it's one of the [System Folder Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905(v=vs.85).aspx#system_folder_properties), pre-defined by Windows Installer.

You should probably specify a name for your TEST directory. See [Directory Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/directory.html):

*Do not specify this attribute (or the LongName attribute) if this directory represents the same directory as the parent (see the Windows Installer SDK's Directory table topic for more information about the "." operator).*